# How do I animate constraint changes if constraints are created programmatically with VFL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

I have trouble on something, I would be grateful if you could give me some advice.

Basically, I created some constraints with Visual Format Language and  makes my base more dynamic. I didn't touch my views on storyboard.

You can consider red area as a navigationBar.

In example view looks like;

[image]

My problem is; I want to hide my topView on some viewController.

First I created a property;

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *constraintTabbarHeight;
```

But I realized I couldn't set my ***NSLayoutConstraint*** property with VFL. Because VFL is create an array of constraints.

**So this is my first question;
Is there anyway to keep my VFL constraint with NSLayoutConstraint property?**

Anyway, so I decided to create my height constraint with ***constraintWithItem*** method.

```
self.constraintTabbarHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tabbarContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:95];
```

Second, I search on stackoverflow and I have found a method. I can call this method from any viewController I want.

```
- (void)updateTabbarConstraintWith:(int) heightValue{
    self.constraintTabbarHeight.constant = heighValue;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];
}
```

If I set self.constraintTabbarHeight.constant = 0 ,everything is fine. My TopView (redArea) is disappearing but PlaceholderView is still on same position.

I thought [self.view layoutIfNeeded] will update my placeholder View and it fills my screen.

It looks like this;

[image]

**How do I make it correct?**

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a constraint from your placeholderView.Top to your TopView.Bottom, otherwise, one will be able to move without impacting the other one